# Get a factorygirl created object in cucumber steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot

I'm using cucumber and factory girl with very good results, but I'm finding that the syntax is a little bit forced.

Assuming there are valid factories for my model, I'd like a generic cucumber helper/step

```
Given a model exists
When I visit the model's edit page
```

I know the portion of the step going to the page but having the step know that #{the model} is refering to an instance would that would go in edit_model_path(@model) is what I'm looking for.

As always, thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the a string in representing the class...so for the class Thing, use the string 'thing'. Once you have this in a step you should be good to go, I'd think...

You could probably use the class name to build up the URL to your edit page. You can actually get the class constant from it's name using this code :

```
my_model = "thing".classify.constantize
my_instance = my_model.find(...)
```

I think this would let you generalize the step enough, no?

Comment: With factory girl, you don't need the Given step if you use the syntax that the OP used. I think they were looking for a way to visit the edit path without needing to define a new step for every model though.

Comment: ah, I completely misunderstood. Let me clear that stuff out and try again :)

Comment: this is great thank you, I think I'm almost there but I spoke too soon in that I'm having trouble building the path dynamically so that it resolves to  `model_edit_path(my_instance)`

Comment: Try using the send method in the features/support/paths.rb. send("model_edit_path".intern, :id => my_instance.id)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [pickle](https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle), it gives you that exact functionality. After you've added the gem to your Gemfile you run the `rails g pickle --paths --email` command you can write steps like

```
# assuming you have an User class and a Factory for that model
Given a user exists
And another user exists with role: "admin"

# later
Then a user should exist with name: "Fred"
And that user should be activated # this uses rspec predicate matchers
```

For your question about paths you can do this (remember the `--paths` option in the generator)

```
Scenario: Show product
    Given a product exists with name: "Milk", price: "2.99"
    When I go to the show page for that product
    Then I should see "Milk" within "h1"
    And I should see "$2.99"
```

More examples in the [readme file](https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle) and in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/186-pickle-with-cucumber)

Comment: Thanks, I already use pickle and it's very close to what I'm asking.  Just to clarify (and it might be purely aesthetic) but I would prefer to use the factory-girl model generation process/syntax - plus keeping it to one gem to do the work just seems neater to my mental wellbeing. Maybe I'm just looking for too much..